# Customize URL in MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new in Asp.net MVC. I am struck at my Customize URL Routing problem.
I have created my Controller named "Customer" and action as "DisplayCustomer".
In Global.asax.cs page,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
             new
             {
                 controller = "Customer",
                 action = "DisplayCustomer",
                 id = UrlParameter.Optional
             }); // Parameter defaults//, new { Code = @"\d{1001,1002}" }
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what wrong in it,it is always showing 
as

```
http://localhost:50415/Views/Customer/DisplayCustomer.aspx
```

not as

```
http://localhost:50415/Customer/DisplayCustomer
```

Am I missing something to make it this to work?

Comment: how do you create this url? In a View with @Html.Action? In this scenario the default route would be enough to create your desired url format. Have a look inside this file in the ASP.NET MVC Internet Template: App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

Comment: What happens if you manually type in the expected URL?

Comment: @ glosrob :It is working if manually Typed URL

Comment: @Andreas: I have created this URL.If I manually typed means,it is working and breaking is hitting App_start,it shows that route is added but it is not pointing to the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Replicated your problem*

1. Select Project Properties
2. Select Web Tab

Now, See the highlighted part in screen shot below

### **Original Version**

[image]

### **Modified Version**

[image]

Removed the View Directory and .cshtml extension. This happened because you set the start Page.

Selecting the Current Page will fix your issue

[image]

Comment: If I specify URL in properties,it is pointing well.But will take App_start route or this properties URL.

Comment: @MahaSwetha : **But will take App_start route or this properties URL** ?

Comment: ,If I mentioned it in properties,it is routing fine.else it is not working.

Comment: @MahaSwetha : It's because you may have set the Start page

Answer (score 0):

This url: `http://localhost:50415/Views/Customer/DisplayCustomer.aspx` is probably opening up in your Browser when you run/debug your project while the current active document in Visual Studio is the `DisplayCustomer` view, try to close this document and re-run the project (i think the problem is fixed for MVC 4 projects).

More importantly, your `Routes` are not correctly defined. if you want to access your `Action` using the default pattern (`{Controller}/{Action}` and in your case `/Customer/DisplayCustomer`) you don't have to write any custom route, just leave the default route as is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL pattern
    new { Id = UrlParamter.Optional });
```

Now, the standard way to get the Url pointing to your `Action` (from within your Controller/View) is to use the `Url.Action` method. for example: `Url.Action("DisplayCustomer", "Customer")`.

Comment: I am trying with MVC 2.I closed the doument and tried,still not working.Is there any workaround for that in MVC 2.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Not Working'? what's happening when you're running the project? also, please show your full `Global.asax`.

Comment: Added Full Global.asax. And as suggested by PKKG below,I removed those web properties,executed,URL is not point as excepted,it is just showing as http://localhost:50415/.Where as,if I mention in web properties,it is pointing fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change "Views" to "Default"

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new {
   controller = "Customer",
   action = "DisplayCustomer",
   id = UrlParameter.Optional
     }); // Parameter defaults
 }
```