# Mvc4 Querystring parameter is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In Asp.net MVC4 I have created below URL showing 404 error with IIS8.0

> http://{ParentURL}/Areas/Admin/Menu/Index?actoin=Add

Please help me on it.

Comment: Do you use the default route? You should have a "Menu" controller in the "Admin" area and the action/view should be "Index".

Comment: **[Check this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802820/customize-url-in-mvc-not-working/17803140#17803140)**

Comment: Problem is with only query sring parameters only other wise working fine but when i pass ?mode = Add then 404 error is coming? so i have mane new route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You URL `http://{ParentURL}/Areas/Admin/Menu/Index?mode=Add` goes to:

**Area:** Admin

**Controller:** Menu

**Action + View:** Index

**Parameter:** mode

So in MenuController.cs (under Admin area) you should have this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string mode)
{
   //code
   return View();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Change your URL to: `http://{ParentURL}/Admin/Menu/Index?mode=Add`

The parameters of your Action must have the same name as in your route declaration.
Also another mistake is to use `Areas` in your URL, you can remove it or change your default route.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string mode)
{
   return View(ViewMenuModel);
}
```

View:

```
var JsSuccessAction = '@Url.Content("~/Admin/Menu/Index?mode=Add")';
```

Route:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
context.MapRoute( "Admin_default", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
}
```

Comment: Controller
======================
public ActionResult Index(string mode)
{

  return View(ViewMenuModel);
}

View
=====================

var JsSuccessAction = '@Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Menu/Index?mode=Add")';


public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            
            
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Yes you don't need the area name, if you want it your have to add it to your route declaration.

Comment: Yes, Right Areas is creating the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a route in route config :

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Areas",
    "Areas/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

add this to your root config and try .. will work

Comment: I need to add also with Routes.config, it is already added with Admin Area Routes

Comment: Your route is wrong, he needs to add "Admin" in the route, check at my answer.